# How to use display slideshow items correctly in React?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, components, slideshow, array.prototype.map

This slideshow is rendering an array of items instead of individual items. I think I need to split up the array in order to get it right. see my link here: https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-waterfall-gqekv?file=/slideshow2.js . My log shows that mapped items is an array, does that mean i need to use splice or spread somehow?

I need each slide to say one name, not the whole array on one slide. If I remove the DUMMY COMPONENT it works fine for some reason?

```
import React from "react";
import AliceCarousel from "react-alice-carousel";
import "react-alice-carousel/lib/alice-carousel.css";



const items = [{ name: "Bob" }, { name: "jill" }, { name: "wesker" }];

let mappeditems = items.map((item, index) => <div key={index}>{item}</div>);

console.log(mappeditems);
console.log(Array.isArray(mappeditems));

const Gallery = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <AliceCarousel mouseTracking items={items}>
        {mappeditems}
        <div>DUMMYCOMPONENT</div>
      </AliceCarousel>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Gallery;
```

Comment: try `<AliceCarousel mouseTracking items={mappeditems}></AliceCarousel>` or `<AliceCarousel mouseTracking items={[...mappeditems, <div>DUMMYCOMPONENT</div>]}></AliceCarousel>`

Comment: You are a GOD. two other developers could not figure this one out. Probably because dependencies aren't friendly sometimes. Thank you! Either answer worked, but I used both ways in two different slideshows (in the link I provided) and they worked! should show working now thank you so much been on this for days.